# How do you access plans in RTC using the REST API?

Tags: rest, rtc

I need to access plans that are defined in Rational Team Concert (Change and configuration management) using the REST API provided by RTC. I am able to access work items, but cannot find URLs and definition how to access plans and query information from them.

Specifically, I want to retrieve the number of "completed hours" and "planned hours" of a plan. These values are shown in the "Current..." widget on the dashboard, the widget that shows all current plans.

The reason why I need to retrieve these values is to create a chart which displays the number of completed hours on a time line. Looks like there is no existing RTC report available.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on the RTC planning component for a time and I'm sorry to say there is no REST API related to plans.